# How to save "scroll state" of PDF file in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Chrome does not save the "scroll state" of a PDF file.

(Try opening a PDF file, closing the tab, and then re-opening it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. Or restart the browser after selecting "Settings" → "On startup" → "Continue where you left off".)

How can we enable this behavior?

Is there a flag to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm), it's the firefox pdf reader for Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: But does it save the "scroll state" of the PDF.. as the question states?

Comment: Yes it save the "scroll state".

Comment: @GastónCaruso, Nice this works as expected, though there are some minor problems (it hijacks all responses that have `Content-Type: application/pdf` even when the responses are non 2xx, e.g. it shouldn't try to interpret the link https://tmoffices.eu/o19314.pdf because the response code is 303). Will be accepting this answer until a better one comes along. Btw, any disclaimers?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is possible in Chrome, but if you fire up adobe reader, which Chrome uses, there is a setting to "remember last document view."

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: I included a screen shot.

Comment: No. Chrome should of installed Adobe reader along with the browser. At least mine does.  Type `adobe reader` into the start menu.

Comment: ok, but it doesn't work. i mean it works in the reader, but not when I use chrome to view it.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome uses its own version of Acrobat Reader.  A lot of functionality that is available in Acrobat's Reader, as well as viewers in other browsers, is severely lacking.  Another example is the ability to rotate a PDF (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>) do not work in chrome, yet work in IE and FF.

Chrome's development team has basically said that fixing this functionality is not a high priority for them.  People have been complaining about these, and other PDF issues for several Chrome versions.  I wouldnt hold my breath for a fix any time soon.

Comment: i was thinking there might be some way since chrome does save our "scroll state" for webpages..

Comment: Chrome has a built-in PDF reader and does not (by default) use Acrobat Reader, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t quite what you asked for, but you can add “#page=35” to the location bar and press enter and it will jump to that page.

If you close Chrome and reopen when it restores tabs the document will jump to that page again.

This won’t work in webpages where the PDF is in a frame or when you open the same PDF later, but makes it possible to have bookmarks/links that jump to particular page.

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time without you accepting an answer, so I hope this will help.

In Chrome, you will either be using `Adobe PDF Reader` (If installed) or the built in Chrome Reader.

If you are having problems with one, I recommend you try the other. You can take a look at `about:plugins` and disable the one that is currently set.

If you are using the built in Chrome one and do not have Adobe PDF Reader installed, try installing it and restarting then setting it here.

Comment: i've tried both but both doesn't work